# Mapping 2D labyrinth from sensor data

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using python 3.7 to process data from a set of ultrasonic sensors (HC-SR04) and an encoder placed on a moving robot. There are 8 ultrasonic sensors which are located on all four corners of the robot, facing front, sideways and backwards, and these give me the distance from their location to any nearby walls or lack thereof. The encoder is placed on a wheel and gives the distance travelled at the instant of sampling.

The objective here is to use the data from these sensors to map the path taken by the robot through a labyrinth and thus create the map for the labyrinth. And that's where I'm stuck, I've already ran the data through a filter to clean up the noise and I've managed to visually determine the path taken by the robot, i.e. if it's driving towards a wall, if it's turned left or right, but having upwards of four thousands data entries this is not ideal.

I'm looking for guidance or ideas on how to determine wether the robot is moving North, South, East or West and also how to create an image to display the path taken and furthermore the map of the labyrinth.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I'm adding graphs from the first 120 data points [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFoIa.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ou9cp.png),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0maa.png),[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBPGn.png), as well as the placement of the sensors[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWfTE.png)

Comment: Does the robot move precisely in the four cardinal directions (N/S/E/W)?  How does the single encoder tell you the 2D velocity, do you know which direction you're moving or only the speed (magnitude)?  A few lines of example data would help.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have very little information about the actual movements of the robot as I have to determine all of its movements through the sensor data. I've added some images from which I was able to determine that during those instants the robot approached a wall, then turned left and approached a wall again. As for the encoder, I get an increasing counter (1,2,3..), where each data point indicates a 0.5cm displacement, so if I read (3) from the encoder it means it has travelled 1.5 cm.